# MVC JsonResult has data, but browser has none

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the controller method GetLayer2().  It is extremely similar to GetLayer0() and GetLayer1()

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetLayer2(string datePassedIn, string eventType, string driverId)
{
    string orgCode = "HVO"; //User.Identity.GetOrgCode();
    DateTime? processDate;
    DateTime defaultDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);  //default yesterday 

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(datePassedIn))
    {
        _logger.LogError(String.Format("Date passed in was NULL or empty. Using default date {0}", defaultDate.ToString(inputDateFormat)), null);
        processDate = defaultDate;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            processDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datePassedIn, inputDateFormat, cultureProvider);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error formatting date {datePassedIn} did not match {inputDateFormat}. using default date {defaultDate}", null);
            processDate = defaultDate;
        }
    }

    driverId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(driverId);


    IEnumerable<EventTypeLayer2> results = await _context.EventTypeLayer2Results
                                                        .FromSql($"usp_dd_EventType_2 @p0, @p1, @p2, @p3", orgCode, processDate, eventType, driverId)
                                                        .ToListAsync();


    JsonResult jr = Json(results);
    return jr;
}
```

The code can be summed up as:

- Get the OrgCode
- Get and parse the datePassedIn to the processDate
- UrlDecode the driverId
- Execute a stored proc, putting the output in results
- Convert results to Json (This was added to aid in troubleshooting)
- return the converted results

Originally it was `return Json(results);`  When debugging the `jr` value has the correct Value results

[image: Image of paused VS session showing value of <code>jr</code>]

When viewed in the browser (Chrome) in the network tab, I get the correct count of objects, but they are all empty.

[image: Image of results in Network tab]

**How do I get my results?**

Edit - added class definition.  Although these are EF classes, they are being filled by stored procedures.

```
[DataContract]
public class EventTypeLayer2
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Key]
    public Int64 RowId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string EventTypeDisplay { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string EventTypeId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string DriverId { get; set; }

    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public int FirstLogId { get; set; }

    public int LastLogId { get; set; }

    public int MinSpeed { get; set; }

    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }

    public int AvgSpeed { get; set; }

    public int CalcSummOdo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `[DataContract]` attribute for `EventTypeLayer2` class, but you did not provide `[DataMember]` attribute for any of the class properties.

[From documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

> You must also apply the DataMemberAttribute to any field, property, or
>   event that holds values you want to serialize.

This is the reason you are getting the right count of the objects, but without any valid member.

Possible solutions:

1) Remove the `[DataContract]` attribute from the class. By default, all public properties will be serialized.

2) Add `[DataMember]` attribute to properties you wish to serialize.

Comment: I added DataMembers to the properties, and after I removed some code I'd added while experimenting, it worked!

Comment: Soz, thought bounty went automatically